# Least common multiple

Tags: python, algorithm

How to calculate the least common multiple of the numbers x and y, if we know the number z and by the condition x + y = z.
The answer does not work(

```
z = int(input())

ls = list(range(1, z))
my_ls = []

for i in ls:
    if z % i == 0:
        my_ls.append((i, z-i))
    else:
        continue

print(*min(my_ls))
```

Comment: Starting with Python 3.9 the `math` built-in module has an [`lcm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.lcm) function

Comment: If z is even, the answer must be z/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the first part, the x+y=z, but now you need to find the lcm for each (x,y). This should do the trick:

```py
from math import lcm
print(*min(((i,lcm(i[0],i[1])) for i in my_ls), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

This will calculate the lcm for each pair (x,y) you found earlier. It then selects the minimum value. It prints the pair `i` and the found `lcm(x,y)`.

To just get the 2 numbers, use:

```py
print(*min(((i,lcm(i[0],i[1])) for i in my_ls), key=lambda x: x[1])[0])
```

Comment: Ou. Thanks.And how to display just two numbers, without a sum?

Comment: Added that to the post!

Answer (score 1):

Your code only looks at the possible pairs of values of  and , but you're not calculating the least common multiple of those pairs.

However, it is not necessary to really produce all those ,  pairs. There is a shortcut here. Find out what the least integer divisor is of the given number  (greater than 1), and then use that to give the required answer. If there is no such divisor (i.e. the given input is prime), then the answer is −1.

```
def solve(z):
    for div in range(2, int(z ** 0.5) + 1):
        if z % div == 0:  # found a divisor
            return z * (div - 1) // div
    return z - 1  # z is prime

print(solve(25))  # 20
```

The returned number is also the value of  that gives this least common multiple, so you also know the value of  (i.e. −).